# Q: How can I fully handle wallets and transactions without any user confirmation?

Tags: web3js, contract-development, transactions, contract-design, metamask

I am attempting to create a messenger DApp for a small group of users. My goal is to avoid things like transaction signage popups and wallet funds by paying and signing everything for all users in the backend. I want the application to have 1 big wallet in the backend that my application is connected to and when a user attempts to send a message it will sign the message and use funds from the big wallet instead of the accounts that the users are connected to on metamask. Is this possible to do and how would I go about it?

Comment: I do not understand the question. Do you know how to do it (without your user story) ? If yes. Then nothing is different. Downside of your model: If i spam your application, I can deplete your account. Hope you are rich !

Comment: @Itération122442 I know how I want to implement the messenger part, I just don't know how to sign and pay transactions for the users messages without a confirmation. I am quite new to DApp development so this is for learning process purposes and everything will be placed on test networks so there's no worries about using real money.

Comment: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send

Comment: @DanBotzu If you don't want the user to sign or approve a transaction the only option is to not use blockchains.